# Как правильно создать окно без фона и с прозрачными объектами? ( C++, GDI+ )

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Для создания программы-оверлея мне необходимо создать полностью прозрачное окно (без фона) на котором можно будет рисовать полу-прозрачные и НЕ прозрачные объекты при помощи GDI+. Я попытался создать окно при помощи CreateWindowExA со стилями WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT и WS_POPUP, оно вроде бы прозрачное, но как только я добавляю отрисовку каких-либо полу-прозрачных объектов через GDI+ получается так что окно как-бы "сохраняет" пиксели которые были под ним в момент отрисовки и вся полу-прозрачность пропадает. Я пробовал добавлять стиль WS_EX_LAYERED, но тогда окно вообще пропадает.

[image: Запуск программы без стиля WS_EX_LAYERED]

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {

        }

        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
            Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(128, 255, 0, 0));
            g.DrawLine(&pen, 0, 0, 100, 100);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }

        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }

        break;

        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiPlusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiPlusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    const char CLASS_NAME[] = "test";

    WNDCLASSA wc = { };

    //wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassA(&wc);

    int width  = 148;
    int height = 140;

    int x = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) / 2) - (width / 2);
    int y = (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) / 2) - (height / 2);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, CLASS_NAME, "test", WS_POPUP, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

    if (!hwnd)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiPlusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чём моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

После создания окна со стилем `WS_EX_LAYERED` окно не будет отображено, пока не будет вызвана `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` или `UpdateLayeredWindow`. А вообще для создания полупрозрачных окон существует современное API DirectComposition.

Кроме того, для создания окна следует использовать `CreateWindowExW`.

Comment: Добавление стиля WS_EX_LAYERED и вызов функции SetLayeredWindowAttributes позволил изменить прозрачность окна, однако вместе с прозрачностью окна меняется прозрачность всего что я на нём рисую при помощи GDI+. Баг с "сохранением" пикселей которые были под формой в момент создания остался. Вот скриншот. https://imgur.com/a/oUW18KU

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте мне что-нибудь чтобы я смог добиться желаемого результата.

Comment: Правильно, SetLayeredWindowAttributes задает прозрачность всего окна, если нужно задавать прозрачность отдельных пикселей, то следует рисовать их с альфа каналом.