# Создание прозрачного окна с поддержкой непрозрачных / полупрозрачных объектов

Tags: c++, winapi

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы на прозрачном окне можно было создавать объекты любой прозрачности и чтобы эта прозрачность не зависела от окна.

Вот скриншот-пример программы сделанной на java

[image: example]

На скриншоте видно что прозрачность объекта который находится в окне не зависит от прозрачности формы.
У меня получилось реализовать окно с поддержкой любой прозрачности при помощи вот этого кода.

```
HWND hwnd CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, wc.lpszClassName, L"window", WS_POPUP, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 150, LWA_ALPHA);
```

Но прозрачность того что я помещаю в окно так же меняется. Мне нужно сделать так как на скриншоте выше.

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1201661/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-c-gdi

Comment: Рад встретить Вас снова. К сожалению там нету ответа на мой вопрос. Вы посоветовали мне использовать SetLayeredWindowAttributes что я и сделал, но это не решило мою проблему. Объекты всё так же зависят от прозрачности окна.

Comment: Так я же там в комментарии пояснил еще по поводу SetLayeredWindowAttributes .

Comment: Простите, но я не понимаю как рисовать с альфа каналом..

Comment: Для этого надо сделать битмап с альфа каналом и рисовать на нем, а не на самом окне, а затем переносить его на dc окна (что кстати делает UpdateLayeredWindow).

Comment: Везде какие-то примеры с изображением, я не понимаю.. :(

Comment: В случае если я сделаю при помощи bitmap, его можно будет "растянуть" при необходимости изменения размеров окна? Или придётся каждый раз лезть в photoshop и делать новый bitmap?

Comment: bitmap следует делать програмно

Comment: Ого, я думал так нельзя. Он делается при помощи CreateBitmap?

Comment: Bitmap — единственный способ сделать так как я хочу? Я читал, есть какой-то bitmap из GDI+ и обычный bitmap (функция для создания выше) Какой лучше использовать и почему? Как правильно его создавать? Я пытался искать примеры, но у меня возникает много разных вопросов, почему делается так а не иначе. Пожалуйста, помогите мне с этим. :(